# Xaml wp7 wp8 code share namespace with mvvm

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light, xml-namespaces

I have a solution with wp7 and wp8 proyects. I share 90% of code between these 2 projects. The only thing I can not share is xaml files because there is a namespace that make this imposible and there is no conditional compilation in xaml. in wp7 the declaration is

```
xmlns:Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP71"
```

and in wp8 is

```
xmlns:Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP8"
```

Is there a way I can create a alias of these namespaces out of the xaml so I can share 100% my xaml between projects? or this is a posibility that mvvmlight assembly names are compiled as the same result assembly filename as other nugget libraries I´m using?

Comment: UPDATE: I ended downloading the mvvmlight code and recompiling it changing the namespaces to make soame dll name in both projects.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the PCL version of the MVVM Light Toolkit.

As far as I know, they behave the same, but you will be sharing the same DLL and thus the same namespace

Comment: I have tried PCL version and the namespaces are diferent , one end in wp75 and other wp8, so same problem :S